# Prepopulate a Models property

Tags: c#, asp.net

What i'm trying to do is create a new model that will have certain features:

```
public class GenericGoal
{
    public int _id { get; set; }
    public List<String> Type_of_Goal { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

my quick and small question would be, how would I prepopulate the `Type_of_goal` field?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at Object initilaizer for example? Or having a constructor or even just accessing the property?

Comment: Multiple ways buddy, Constructor is a standard way during initialization

Answer (score 0):

You could give the property 'Type_of_Goal' an initial value, if you don't want to have to initialize it every time, or initialize it when no value is set to it.

```
public class GenericGoal
{
    public int _id { get; set; }
    public List<String> Type_of_Goal { get; set; } = new List<String>();
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

If it is 'NullReferenceException' you are concerned about, check for null's before accessing the 'Type_of_Goal' property, as follow. Note the **? - Known as Null Propagation Operator**

```
genericGoalInstance.Type_of_Goal?.Add("Good Goal");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a constructor for this; could look like this example.

```
public class GenericGoal
{
    public int _id { get; set; }
    public List<String> Type_of_Goal { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public GenericGoal()
    {
        Type_of_Goal = new List<String>();
    }
}
```

I recommend the initialisation in the constructor because in my opinion it's cleaner and better readable.